# How to store all JSON records into SQLite

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am parsing a JSON and trying to store that JSON data into SQLite database, I have only `name` attribute in my JSON and have around 15 records, but i am not able to store all records into SQLite - still only storing last parsed record into JSON.

Here is how my JSON looks like:

```
{
  "actors": [
    {
      "name": "Name 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Name 2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Name 3"
    },
    .......
    {
      "name": "Name 15"
    }
  ]
}
```

**How may i store all records into JSON ?** As you can see in my JSON i have 15 records, but in SQLite i am getting data only for the last JSON record (i.e - Name 15)

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {

        //------------------>>
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                Actors actor = new Actors();

                actor.setName(object.getString("name"));                        

                actorsList.add(actor);                      

                sqliteDB.open();

                sqliteDB.deleteAll();                                           

                sqliteDB.insert(object.getString("name"));

                sqliteDB.close();
            }
            return true;
        }

        //------------------>>

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: why are you calling this in loop sqliteDB.deleteAll(); ?

Comment: if i am not wrong you are deleting the record after inserting a item what when you are calling sqliteDB.deleteAll();

Comment: wait a minute let me check that .. @SyedRazaMehdi

Comment: use the code i posted hope it is the mistake you are doing and i prefer that you don't open and close the db connection in loop it must be done outside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");
                sqliteDB.open(); 
                sqliteDB.deleteAll();  
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("name"));                        

                    actorsList.add(actor);                      

                    sqliteDB.insert(object.getString("name"));

                }
                 sqliteDB.close();
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: hey yes it has been worked for me, let's make a small change in your code call sqliteDB.open() before sqliteDB.deleteAll() ...

Comment: yes you are right missed that one :P, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

in the for loop before insert a record , you are deleting all the data from database , that's why only last record you are getting, try the below code

```
sqliteDB.open();
        sqliteDB.deleteAll();  
        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

            Actors actor = new Actors();

            actor.setName(object.getString("name"));                        

            actorsList.add(actor);                      

            sqliteDB.insert(object.getString("name"));

        }
         sqliteDB.close();
```

Comment: i have ticked your answer as useful :)